# how to embed a link inside an image?

Tags: java, html, jakarta-ee

I am trying to generate a jpg/bmp/png certificate in my web app. Can I encode a URL inside this logo such that, whenever it's clicked, it's redirected to the online profile?

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a:

- Anchor: `<a href="http://www.google.com/"><img src="..."/></a>`
- Image Map: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

It's common practice now to use CSS to set the images using the **image-background** property.

Comment: "...to set the images..." of what? Can you make an `image-background` a hyperlink?

Comment: See this for a guide: http://bluedogwebservices.com/css-trick-turning-a-background-image-into-a-clickable-link/

Comment: Interesting, thanks for that. If he's just showing an image, though, it's probably easier for him to wrap it in an anchor as in your first suggestion.

Comment: Not exactly what i am looking for,wanted to know if i could encode in the Binary of the image.

Answer (score 1):

use html tag area with map tag

e.g

```
<img src ="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap ="#planetmap" />

<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="sun.htm" alt="Sun" />
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="mercur.htm" alt="Mercury" />
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="venus.htm" alt="Venus" />
</map>
```

[src](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_areamap)

Answer (score 0):

You can't encode an image with a URL but the turning images into hyperlinks was a problem solved many years ago...

[HTML Links](http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_links.asp)

Comment: Well you can encode images with a URL (Data URIs) ... but I don't think that's what you mean! :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - the URL is stored in the image as metadata? Can you use that to link to another page?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme explains Data URIs, which shows you how to encode an image using a URL. I was being pedantic, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

What i was exactly looking for was coding the link into image binary. and i got my answer

We can not embed a hyper link into the binary data of a graphic such as jpg, bmp and gif.
This is for two main reasons ,

1. Security. When we give the image format a chance to execute
   something like code or a hyperlink we are essentially creating a gap
   from which exploits may arise.
2. Relevance. An image file is that
       *just an image* if we want to move to a format which allows code to be executed in a rich media environment. flash is only option
   Most
       of the social media sites won't allow redirection from there profile
       image to an external link .

Regards,
Abhishek Ranjan